# Formulario repetido en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente script en PHP:

```
<?php 
if (
    !isset($_GET["nombre"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["cuit_tipo"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["cuit_dni"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["cuit_al"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["iva"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["direccion"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["num"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["piso"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["puerta"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["ciudad"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["provincia"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["cp"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["pais"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["codigo_area"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["telefono"]) ||
    !isset($_GET["email"])
)

include "conexion.php";
$found = false;
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM proveedores WHERE nombre=\"$_POST[nombre]\"";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
    $found = true;
    break;
    } if($found){
        print "<script>alert(\"El nombre del proveedor ya está registrado.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE proveedores SET nombre = \"$_POST[nombre]\", cuit_tipo = \"$_POST[cuit_tipo]\", cuit_dni = \"$_POST[cuit_dni]\",  cuit_al = \"$_POST[cuit_al]\", iva = \"$_POST[iva]\", direccion =\"$_POST[direccion]\", num = \"$_POST[num]\", piso = \"$_POST[piso]\", puerta = \"$_POST[puerta]\", ciudad = \"$_POST[ciudad]\", provincia = \"$_POST[provincia]\", cp = \"$_POST[cp]\", pais = \"$_POST[pais]\", codigo_area = \"$_POST[codigo_area]\", telefono = \"$_POST[telefono]\", email = \"$_POST[email]\", created_at = NOW() WHERE nombre = \"$_POST[nombre]\"";
        print $sql;
            $query = $con->query($sql);
            if($query!=null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Registro exitoso.\");window.location='../editar_proveedor.php';</script>";
            }
?>
```

La idea de este script es el de actualizar los datos de una tabla de proveedores.
La página anterior a esta, toma los datos de la tabla, los ingresa a unos `<input>` para que la información pueda editarse.

El script está programado para que, por un lado, reconozca el nombre del proveedor y que no guarde un mismo nombre para que no se interpongan los nombres de los proveedores o, mejor dicho, para que dos filas no tengan el mismo nombre.

Lo que me sucede es que en el input del nombre, de no haber cambios, salta el `alert` de que el **nombre ya está registrado**, porque reconoce ese nombre como el mismo que ya está en la tabla.
La idea es que si el nombre no tiene cambios, no salte ese mensaje y guarde los cambios.

Por otro lado, al editar los demás datos y correr el script, los datos se guardan y sigue saltando el mensaje de **el nombre ya está registrado**.

La idea final, es hacer que el script haga 3 cosas:

1. Identificar si el nombre se corresponde con otro nombre y no el que queda pendiente de edición, que sería el mismo que ya tenemos en la tabla.
2. Guardar los datos editados, con el mensaje **registro exitoso**.
3. Si se edita el nombre y éste se corresponde con otro nombre ya registrado, salte el alert con **el nombre ya está registrado** y que no salga de la página, sino que quede en el mismo lugar para poder volver a editar los datos hasta dar con la información correcta.

Comment: Para lograr eso debes pasar tambien el id del proveedor que estas editando de esa manera si los nombres no coinciden pero el id si quiere decir que estas editando, sino es que estas intentando crear uno nuevo con el nombre de un proveedor que ya existe, inicialmente pudes poner el id a 0 para saber diferenciar si es una edición o una inserción.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar bindings en tu consulta, no se si habras oido hablar de sql injection con lo que haces en $con->query estas facilitandole a cualquiera que destroce tu base de datos, puedes apoyarte en estas bibliografías: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp, https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php